Nerve theorem for simplicial sets
There are various kinds of nerve theorems. I am wondering if the following version of nerve theorem for simplicial sets is true:
Let $X:\Delta^{\mathrm{op}}\to \mathrm{Set}$ be a simplicial set. Let $\mathcal{A}=\left\{A_j: j\in J\right\}$ be a collection of simplicial sets which is a "good cover" of $X$, i.e. $X=\bigcup_{j\in J} A_j$ and the geometric realisation of any nonempty finite intersection of $A_j$'s is contractible. Then $|X|$ is homotopy equivalent to the nerve complex $N(\mathcal{A})$.
There is a version for simplicial complexes, and the geometric realisation of a simplicial set is a CW complex, which can be made into a simplicial complex by double subdivisions. Therefore, I guess the above statement should be correct. But I did not find a statement like this (for simplicial sets) in the literature. Did I miss something? Any reference or comments would be very much appreciated.

This is indeed well-known. Apply the diagonal lemma to the Cech nerve of the cover. Presumably you can find this in Goerss and Jardine.

"which can be made into a simplicial complex by double subdivisions" Is this really that simple? If I remember correctly, there are two different subdivision functors and a natural map $N(Sd(X))->X$ which is only a simple homotopy equivalence.

@HenrikRüping It is not simple. I’m sorry that I didn’t make it clear since I am not very sure about this approach. Maybe it is clearer to think of these simplicial sets as $\Delta$-sets by forgetting the face maps, and then apply the barycentric subdivisions twice to fit in the settings of simplicial complex. But I believe that this statement deserves a more natural proof, instead of trying to transfer the settings to simplicial complexes. The core of nerve theorems is homotopy colimits.

@TimCampion Thank you for your answer, Tim. I am a beginner in the simplicial homotopy theory, and I am trying to grasp your point. If I am understanding correctly, you consider the Čech nerve of the cover as a bisimplicial set, whose diagonal object is weakly equivalent to the homotopy colimit of the diagram of Čech nerve. But how to relate this to X, which I think is the colimit of the diagram?

One aim of my recent article on the Nerve Theorem was to give a simple proof of the result with minimal hypotheses. It applies, for instance, to covers of CW complexes by subcomplexes, and in particular it applies to simplicial sets as in the question. The simplicial set case may well be written down other places, although I don’t recall finding a reference when I was writing the paper.
